# NSObject Class used to set values in nested class manner (Swift 4.0 - Xcode 9.1)

Tags: swift, nsobject

I created a child class of `NSObject` and used the `NSObject` method `setValuesForKeys()` to automatically set my class properties, and it's working fine. But now I set the nested class in this child class to again set values. Here is my code.

```
class User: NSObject {
    private let keys = ["id", "first_name", "last_name"]

    @objc var id: String?
    @objc var first_name: String?
    @objc var last_name: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(dic: [String: Any]) {
        super.init()
        self.setValuesForKeys(dic)
    }
}
```

Ex:

```
let user = User(dic: Dictionary)
user.first_name // Name of User
```

But now I want to do like this..

```
class User: NSObject {
    class Addr: NSObject {
        private let keys = ["block", "zipcode", "country"]

        @objc var block:String?
        @objc var zipcode:String?
        @objc var country:String?

        override init() {
            super.init()
        }   
    }

    private let keys = ["id", "first_name", "last_name", "addr"]

    @objc var id:String?
    @objc var first_name:String?
    @objc var last_name:String?
    @objc var addr:Addr?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(dic: [String: Any]) {
        super.init()
        self.setValuesForKeys(dic)
    }
}
```

And now I need to access like that..

```
let user = User(dic: Dictionary)
user.addr.block // need to get block value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my custom [AGObject](https://github.com/AshvinGudaliya/AGObject)

reason `@objcMembers` Use in Swift 4

When a Swift class introduces many new methods or properties that require behavior from the Objective-C runtime, use the `@objcMembers` attribute in the declaration of that class. Applying the `@objcMembers` attribute to a class implicitly adds the `@objc` attribute to all of its Objective-C compatible members. Because applying the `@objc` attribute can increase the compiled size of an app and adversely affect performance, only apply the `@objcMembers` attribute on declarations when each member needs to have the `@objc` attribute applied.

```
@objcMembers class User: NSObject {
...
}
```